# Pruning flink state based on attributes of stored object

Tags: java, state, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Consider the following example class, instances of which are being stored in a `ListState`:

```
class BusinessObject {
  long clientId;
  String region;
  Instant lastDealDate; 
  bool isActive;
}
```

The application requires that this object shouldn't be in the flink state if it has been 1 year since the last deal was made (`lastDealDate`) with a particular client **and** the client is not active i.e. `isActive == false`

What would be the proper way of going about this and letting flink know of these 2 factors so it removes those entries automatically? Currently, I read all the items in the state, clear the state and then add back the relevant ones, however this will start to take a long time as the number of clients increases and the size of the state grows large. Most of my searches online talk about using `time-to-live` and setting it for my state via `descriptor`. However, my logic can't rely on processing/event/ingestion time and I need to also check if `isActive` is false.

Extra info: the context is not keyed and the backend is RocksDB. The reason a `ListState` is used is because all of the relavant state/history as per the above conditions needs to be dumped every day.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell us why you are using ListState (and how it is used), whether you are operating in a keyed context, and which state backend you are using?

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks for asking, added the answers to your questions to the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the RocksDB state backend, Flink can append to ListState without going through serialization/deserialization, but any read or modification other than an append is expensive because of ser/de.

You'll be better off if you can rework things so that these BusinessObjects are stored in MapState, even if you occasionally have to iterate over the entire map. Each key/value pair in the MapState will be a separate RocksDB entry, and you'll be able to individually create/update/delete them without having to go through ser/de for the entire map (unless you do have to scan it). (For what it's worth, iterating over MapState in RocksDB proceeds through the map in serialized-key-sorted order.)

MapState is only available as keyed (or broadcast) state, so this change would require you to key the stream. Using keyBy does force a network shuffle (and ser/de), so it will be expensive, but not as expensive as using ListState.

Comment: Is we disregard the is `isActive` part, is it possible to direct flink to use our `lastDealDate` as the time to measure from to determine if the object is expired or not?

Comment: No, that's not possible. State TTL is expired based on the time since the last write, or the last read or write, and uses internal timers that you don't have access to.

Comment: So I should go by making this a keyed context, and in my process function I can register a timer to trigger at my desired time e.g. `ctx.timestamp()+myTtl`and do my cleaning in the `onTimer` method? Is that my only way?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that might work would be to write a RocksDB compaction filter to implement your expiration logic. But I don't know enough about compaction filters to know if or how well that would work.

Comment: Right. But at least the timer approach can be a reasonable workaround?

Comment: Yes, I don't expect any problems with the timer-based approach. Gives you complete control.

Comment: Great. There is one timer per key per timestamp, that will mean that timers will need deletion once fired too?

Comment: A timer can only fire once, and once it has fired it is automatically deleted. The only reason to delete a timer is to prevent it from firing.